# Basic shopping cart using array.push();

Tags: javascript

I would like to make a basic shopping cart app in which you can click on items, every click should add the item to an array.  At the end you should be able to press a total button and see all the items you have added, but so far it's not working.

Code so far:

```
function add() {

var shoppingCart = [];

document.getElementById("itemOne").addEventListener("click", function() {
 shoppingCart.push("One");
  });

 document.getElementById("itemTwo").addEventListener("click", function() {
  shoppingCart.push("Two")
   });

 document.getElementById("total").addEvenetListener("click", function() {

document.getElementById("display").innerHTML =
  shoppingCart;
})
}
```

Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xpb8oarx/

Comment: Define _"it's not working"_! Can you share executable demo/snippet or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) ? [_Create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example_](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Editted original and added a JSFiddle.

Comment: you never call the function `add()`, and it contains a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Typo @ `addEventListener`
- Never called `add()` you do not need that anyways

```js
var shoppingCart = [];
document.getElementById("itemOne").addEventListener("click", function() {
  shoppingCart.push("One");
});

document.getElementById("itemTwo").addEventListener("click", function() {
  shoppingCart.push("Two");
});

document.getElementById("total").addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = shoppingCart;
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 70%;
  background-color: black;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#itemOne,
#itemTwo {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  margin: 1%;
  color: white;
}
#display {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div id="itemOne" class="itemOne">
    <button class=" item">Chicken</button>
  </div>

  <div id="itemTwo">
    <button class="item">Veggies</button>
  </div>

  <button id="total">Total</button>
  <h1 id="display"></h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Will accept the answer when it allows me, it works as expected, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You'll find a tutorial [HERE](http://marcautran.developpez.com/tutoriels/javascript/panier/) which explain how to implement a cart in pure HTML5 and Vanilla.
Tuto written by a french JS ninja